# Yii2 как сохранить запись через связующую таблицу?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет.
Генерировал через Gii (model/Grud). При сохранении записи Page у меня категория не записывается.

И в форме какое поля я должен заюзать чтобы можно было выбирать категории для страницы? 
Подскажите как эта фича работает (со связями 1 ко многим это понятно)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, кстати, не увидел код контроллера, где происходит сохранение модели. И не надо скрином, есть же тэги для кода.

Answer (score 0):

У **Page** еще должна быть реляция к **PageCategory**, а не только к **page_to_category**. И реляцию эту необходимо описать через метод `via()`, в который передать название реляции.

```
public function getPageToCategory()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PageToCategory::class, ['page_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getPageToCategory()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PageCategory::class, ['id' => 'category_id'])
        ->via('pageToCategory');
}
```

Т.к. нам, по сути, не нужны данные из таблицы **page_to_category**, обычно делают реляцию одним методом с указанием связующей таблицы в методе `viaTable()`.

```
public function getPageCategory()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PageCategory::class, ['id' => 'category_id'])
        ->viaTable('page_to_category', ['page_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Вместо `Item::className()` необходимо использовать `Item::class`

Подробнее про [связывание данных посредством промежуточной таблицы](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/db-active-record#junction-table).