# Как правильно составить связи в моделе Yii2

Tags: yii2, gridview

Постараюсь максимально объяснить суть вопроса. 
У меня есть 3 таблицы: **items**, **rows** и **item_prop**.

Таблица **items** - это список объектов (ключ id), **rows** - список свойств, которые может иметь объект (ключ id), **item_prop** - таблица, которая связывает **items** и **rows** и хранить значение. То есть в ней есть такие поля: item_id, row_id, value. Тут думаю понятно.

Собственно сам вопрос: как правильно в модели описать эти связи, что бы корректно работал GridView, а именно поиск и сортировка. Я только знаю, когда 2 таблицы связаны (через hasOne или hasMany), а тут не знаю как.

Подскажите пожалуйста или ткните в пример. Спасибо

Comment: В этом вопросе я отвечал про связи с промежуточной таблицей https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879140/yii2-как-сохранить-запись-через-связующую-таблицу/879446#879446

Answer (score 0):

К примеру, с таблицы Props берем row_id и prop_id.

```
class SomeClass extends Smth
{
    public function getItem() {
        return $this->hasOne(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id']);
    }

    public function getRow() {
        return $this->hasOne(Props::className(), ['id' => 'row_id']);
    }

    public function getProp() {
        return $this->hasOne(Props::className(), ['id' => 'prop_id']);
    }
}
```

И берем что надо:

```
$props = Props::find()->with('item, row, prop')->all();
foreach ($props as $prop) {
    $item = $prop->item;
    $row = $prop->row;
    $prop = $prop->prop;
}
```

p.s. с yii2 давно работал, но сделать это можно как-то так, вроде бы